# difference between .textContent and .firstChild.data

Tags: javascript, dom

assuming I have a html, with an h2, what's the difference between

```js
document.querySelector('h2').textContent = 'abcdefg';
```

```html
<h2>
</h2>
```

and

```js
document.querySelector('h2').firstChild.data = 'abcdefg';
```

```html
<h2>
</h2>
```

?

I'm mainly interested in knowing what this `.data` is, I didn't find the documentation for it

Comment: I don't think `.data` is a standard DOM property. So this is a custom property being used by the application, the browser ignores it.

Comment: @Barmar but it works in chrome for some reason

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData

Comment: I saw this while studying the "A simple example" part at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Using_the_W3C_DOM_Level_1_Core. I just rewrote it with the querySelector()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one will always work to set the text content of the element in question.

The second will only work if the element's first child is a text node (aka [CharacterData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData)).

For example, using `.data` has no observable change if the first-child is an `Element`.

```js
document.querySelector('#no-text-children').firstChild.data = 'abcdefg';
document.querySelector('#only-text-children').firstChild.data = 'abcdefg';
```

```html
<h2 id="no-text-children"><span>this is the span content</span></h2>
<h2 id="only-text-children">this is the h2 content</h2>
```

Using `.textContent` does not suffer from any such limitations

```js
document.querySelector('#no-text-children').textContent = 'abcdefg';
document.querySelector('#only-text-children').textContent = 'abcdefg';
```

```html
<h2 id="no-text-children"><span>this is the span content</span></h2>
<h2 id="only-text-children">this is the h2 content</h2>
```

Comment: Funny thing, they return different texts sometimes https://imgur.com/zf2AHOp

Comment: @Konrad That will happen if you have whitespace around the `<span>`. Each bit of whitespace is a separate text node.

Comment: so CharacterData is one of the DOM interfaces? as well as Document, Element, Node, NodeList, etc? Is the DOM just the "merger" of all these objects/interfaces? I ask this because I'm reading the MDN articles but I still don't understand the concept of the DOM itself.

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. The [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) is basically the collection of various interfaces that represent the elements in a HTML (or XML) document. `CharacterData` is an extension of [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) which is the base class for most objects

Comment: I'm commenting here just in case someone still has doubts about the subject in the future (please correct me if something is wrong, I'm also learning), all this doubt and others could be summarized by accessing the `nodeType` property of objects that implement the [Node interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)

Comment: The [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) property of the Node interface can be 12 different values: 1 (element Node), 2 (attribute Node), 3 (text Node), ... etc. So in the case of this question, `document.querySelector('h2').firstChild.nodeType` is `3`, because the `document.querySelector('h2').firstChild` node is a [text Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)), so we can access any properties and methods of any interfaces that `Text` implements (`Event Target`, `Node`, `Character Data`).

Comment: So we can access the [data property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData/data) of the [CharacterData interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData)

Comment: Whereas if the <h2> was empty: `<h2></h2>`, `document.querySelector('h2').firstChild.data = 'abcdefg';` results in an error because as <h2> has no child nodes, `document.querySelector('h2').firstChild;` is `null` (
and therefore does not have the data property because it isn't a text Node).